# How to print doctype in FigDice

Tags: php, template-engine

I don't manage to output the

```
 <!doctype html>
```

directive in the rendered view with FigDice Template Engine.
If I put the instruction at top of my XML template, it seems to be ignored.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the

```
<!doctype html>
```

instruction is processed by the XML reader of the FigDice engine itself (although, it does nothing with it).

What you want to do is: begin your FigDice template earlier, and output this sequence inside a `CDATA` node.

```
<fig:template xmlns:fig="http://www.figdice.org/">
<![CDATA[<!doctype html>]]>
    <html>
      ....
    </html>
</fig:template>
```

This is the recommended way as per project's examples:

[examples/example1-getstarted/template-main.xml](https://github.com/gabrielzerbib/figdice/blob/master/examples/example1-getstarted/template-main.xml)